# How to get a list of tuples inside of a list-comprehension

Tags: python, matrix, tuples, append, list-comprehension

there

What I am trying to do is to get a tuple added to a list of tuples inside of a list-comprehension
I have the following code...
subsets =  [list(m).extend(initialMedoid) for m in list(itertools.combinations(distances, 2))]

For instance I have the following data sample:

**INPUT**

```
 initialMedoid = [('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])]
 arr = [[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])]]
```

And I would like to get it as presented in the expected output

But instead I am getting a bunch of nones

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
[[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])],
[('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0]),('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])]]
```

Comment: Minimal example please.

Comment: Hello, @SomeDude
I just need to get this [[('some text', [1,2,3,...]),('other text', [1,2,3,4])], [('some text', [1,2,3,...]),('other text', [1,2,3,4])]] into this [[('some text', [1,2,3,...]),('other text', [1,2,3,4]), ('Still more text', [1,2,3,4])], [('some text', [1,2,3,...]),('other text', [1,2,3,4]), ('Still more text', [1,2,3,4])]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initialMedoid = [('ibis_142', [8.708170812, 0.0, 10.518235207, 7.668395996, 10.522399903, 7.302185059, 6.417022705, 6.146172005, 10.448354985, 5.149291993])]
 arr = [[('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('highway_bost174', [0.0, 8.708170812, 4.088197921, 11.366319879999999, 12.638763287, 11.078233943, 10.025102839, 8.415467337, 8.194840093, 13.455056175000001]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('street_par88', [4.088197921, 10.518235207, 0.0, 11.135904053, 11.472831274, 10.691568116, 9.663827636, 10.659660884000001, 9.392413013999999, 12.586018896]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('opencountry_241', [11.366319879999999, 7.668395996, 11.135904053, 0.0, 13.314941407, 2.754882813, 3.998626709, 9.028326501, 12.145703089000001, 8.675354002999999]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('waterfall23', [12.638763287, 10.522399903, 11.472831274, 13.314941407, 0.0, 12.665527344000001, 11.406341552, 12.6048929, 11.43774673, 8.79888916]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('field26', [11.078233943, 7.302185059, 10.691568116, 2.754882813, 12.665527344000001, 0.0, 3.349212646, 8.966176812, 11.827669236000002, 8.203674316]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001])],
        [('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('mountain_030', [10.025102839, 6.417022705, 9.663827636, 3.998626709, 11.406341552, 3.349212646, 0.0, 8.78585096, 11.994283939999999, 7.7325744620000005]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]), ('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482])],
        [('horse_081', [8.415467337, 6.146172005, 10.659660884000001, 9.028326501, 12.6048929, 8.966176812, 8.78585096, 0.0, 8.054160893999999, 11.093641082000001]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])],
        [('bison_052', [8.194840093, 10.448354985, 9.392413013999999, 12.145703089000001, 11.43774673, 11.827669236000002, 11.994283939999999, 8.054160893999999, 0.0, 12.869559482]), ('ibis_040', [13.455056175000001, 5.149291993, 12.586018896, 8.675354002999999, 8.79888916, 8.203674316, 7.7325744620000005, 11.093641082000001, 12.869559482, 0.0])]]   
secArray = []
    for n in arr: 
      n = list(n)
      n.extend(initialMedoid)
      secArray.append(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to append `initialMedoid` to every list element of `arr`?

```py
subset = [m.append(initialMedoid[0]) for m in arr]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `list.append` in list comprehension and `.append` method return None so at the end you are getting list of `None`

you can directly use the original list instead of output from list comprehention.

check below example:

if you dont care of changing original list you can use `arr` instead of its copy.

```
arr_copy = arr.copy()
[x.extend(initialMedoid) for x in arr_copy]
print(arr_copy)
```

the above code will append `initialMedoid` in each sublist of your `arr`